# How do I echo redirected input, or at least have a blank line represented?

Tags: python, batch-processing

When testing some programs from the console in a Windows batch file I redirect input from a text file and my Python code picks it up fine and produces the required output.

The first line of the output is misaligned however, due to the input not being echoed or a \n not being produced after the prompt.

As a simple example if my program were:

```
variableName = input( "Enter something: " )
print( "You entered:", variableName )
```

And the file a.txt contained:

```
This is a test string.
```

The command `python myprogram.py < a.txt` would give output as:

```
Enter something: You entered: This is some test string.
```

Instead of the more desirable:

```
Enter something: 
You entered: This is some test string.
```

Without changing my python program, is there a simple way to correct this output?  In case it's relevant I'm using Python 3.

PS I am already certain I could massage the output files to remove the offending prompt with further batch processing but I'd rather have a one step process here.

Comment: I don't think you can do much about it without changing anything in the program. You can't change anything in your Python file or you'd just prefer not to?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the input file (a.txt)? If you can't change the code and you can't change the input, what can you change?

Comment: @Ben I can change the input file to anything I like.